# How to Enable Filter functionality in Security area Silverstripe Admin?

Tags: php, silverstripe

How to Enable Filter functionality in Security area  Silverstripe Admin?

Please tell me solution.

here i want to add filter functionality like second screenshot
[image: Here i want to add filter functioanlity]

like this
[image: Like this]

Comment: Of course, that filter functionality is available by clicking the magnifying glass on the top right of the table

Answer (score 2):

Well, SecurityAdmin for some reason doesn't subclass ModelAdmin but LeftAndMain directly. Depending on what you want to do it may be easiest to make your own MemberAdmin as a subclass of ModelAdmin. This has a search form and takes Member's $searchable_fields array into account.

```
class MemberAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    private static $url_segment = 'members';

    private static $managed_models = array(
        'Member'
    );
}
```

would be a simple start for that. You can make a [DataExtension](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataExtension.html) for Member and edit the searchable fields defining a method called `updateSearchableFields()` or defining directly as the `private static $searchable_fields` array.

Comment: I am new on this. so please make steps for this, where we make a new fiile or what matter can i include. Please

Comment: You should go through the lessons (http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/), especially www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/data-extensions-and-siteconfig and http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/introduction-to-modeladmin, but please also the other lessons for a better understanding of silverstripe...

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Company class:

```
static $searchable_fields = array(
    'Title',
    'State',
    'Description',
);
```